# HightChart Error 13 with angular js, function and controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am facing a strange issue with angular js and highchart.

My abstract of code is something like this:

**html**

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div ng-repeat="project in ProjList">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="module-group">
                        <!--Other block - 1-->

                        <section class="module">
                            <div id="tagID{{project.projName}}"></div>
                        </section>  

                        <!--Other module - 2-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

enter code here
```

**Controller**

```
app.service('myService', function(config, myHighChart, $http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    this.loadJSON = function(file, callback) {
        //Code to read JSON file
    }

    this.displayChart = function(myHighChart, highChartData, projName) {

        myHighChart.buildHighChart(highChartData, projName);

        return true;
    };

app.controller('MyCtrl', [
    'config',
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$q',
    '$timeout',
    'myService',
    'myHighChart',
    function(config, $scope, $http, $q, $timeout, myService,
            myHighChart) {
{
                //$scope.ProjList = [ {
                //                    projName: 'Proj1',
                //                    data : 10,        
                //                    }, {
                //                    projName: 'Proj2',
                //                    data : 20,    
                //                    }]; //inside main scope - 1

        myService.loadJSON(fileName, function(response) {
                //There is nothing to do with the Json read here, my plan is to take data from the json file and create dynamic project, but to test I am using sample data

            $scope.ProjList = [ {
                                 projName: 'Proj1',
                                 data : 10,     
                                }, {
                                 projName: 'Proj2',
                                 data : 20, 
                                }];//inside function - 2

            //Prepare highChartData from the ProjList

            //Call HighChart in a loop of ProjList
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.ProjList.length; i++) {
                console.log("Display chart for: "
                        + $scope.ProjList[i].projName);

                var varname = 'show' + $scope.ProjList[i].projName;

                $scope[varname] = myService.displayChart(
                        myHighChart, highChartData, $scope.ProjList[i].projName);
            }           
     )};
}
```

**highchart**

```
app
    .factory(
            'myHighChart',
            function() {
                return {

                    // function for the charts
                    buildHighChart : function(highChartData, projName) {

                    var options = {};

                        options.chart = {
                            renderTo : 'tagID' + projName,
                            zoomType : 'x',
                            marginBottom : 60,
                        };

                        <!--Other required fields are set-->                        

                        console.log("Render to element with ID : " + options.chart.renderTo);
                        console.log("Number of matching dom elements : " + $("#" + options.chart.renderTo).length);

                        new Highcharts.Chart(options);                                  
                    }
```

With the above code I am loading a high chart which has proper renderTo id. 
This gives me,

Render to element with ID : 0

Number of matching dom elements : tagIDProj1

Highcharts error #13

**But when i un-comment "inside main scope - 1" and comment "inside function - 2", then I am able to load the high chart properly.**

Note: There is no changes in the other part of code

Is there any issue with scope? I am clueless here with the controller scope and function scope or am I missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Error#13 occurs when HighCharts.js tries to access an element which is not present in the DOM. I would suggest to check flow of statements execution. You must be dynamically creating the element after HighCharts is looking for it.

Comment: Thanks Jay...Yes I am dynamically creating the element. I have updated my post for the better readability.

Comment: Hi Suraj.. your console log says that the element is not created yet. We need to make sure that the element is present in the DOM before we are rendering the chart to it.